# Can Java Spring boot micro-services be exported as an installation file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am using Java Spring Boot for micro-services. I have multiple micro-services called:

1. Auth Service
2. User Service
3. Account Service
4. Api Gateway Service
5. Discovery Server
6. Config Service
7. UI Service

etc...

I have to download these micro-services as a one-time installation file. How is it possible. What I really needed is to download and install my microservice project into multiple client's systems. It would be a Windows or Linux system environment. So how can I combine all services into one installation file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don’t - if you would have written microservices architecture you would have known the answer to your question:)

anywho what is microservices? These are independent services running most commonly on different servers but even if on the same server still as separate instances/containers so what does that tell you? **You deploy them to the server**. So there is no windows installation like program that will do that for you. Definitely not many different microservices at the same time.

You could write a script which is responsible for containerising these into Docker and then running them in containers but first you should learn how to deploy at least one application just to understand the process. Here is a little guide https://javamondays.com/deploying-spring-boot-on-aws-for-newbies/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
So can you suggest any solution for my requirement. I have to download and install different services as different software like adobe software and need to do Single sign-on authentication schema. 
Thanks in advance.